# using lambda function to download files in snakemake: 'This IOFile is specified as a function and may not be used directly.'

Tags: lambda, snakemake

I am trying to download FASTQ files from an FTP server using snakemake which I'll post-process. Filenames are under columns "read1" and "read2" in `data.tsv`. When I try the following code, I get the following error:

```
ValueError in line 17 ...
This IOFile is specified as a function and may not be used directly.
```

Line 17 refers to `shell`. I tried googling around and the lambda function looks correct - also lambda functions are [accepted](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#non-file-parameters-for-rules) in `params`.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

samples = pd.read_table("data.tsv").set_index("sample", drop=False)

rule all:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: samples.to_dict()["read1"][wildcards.sample].split('/')[-1],
        lambda wildcards: samples.to_dict()["read2"][wildcards.sample].split('/')[-1]

rule dl:
    output:
        temp(lambda wildcards: samples.to_dict()["read1"][wildcards.sample].split('/')[-1]),
        temp(lambda wildcards: samples.to_dict()["read2"][wildcards.sample].split('/')[-1])
    params:
        read1 = lambda wildcards: samples.to_dict()["read1"][wildcards.sample],
        read2 = lambda wildcards: samples.to_dict()["read2"][wildcards.sample]
    shell:
        "wget {params.read1}; wget {params.read2}"
```

Please help - I can't figure out what's wrong.

**EDIT 1**

In case it's helpful, the following code using [remote files](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/remote_files.html#file-transfer-protocol-ftp) works (also suggested by euronion below):

```
import pandas as pd
from snakemake.remote.FTP import RemoteProvider as FTPRemoteProvider

FTP = FTPRemoteProvider()

samples = pd.read_table("data.tsv").set_index("sample", drop=False)

rule all:
    input:
        expand("results/{sample}.sam", sample = samples["sample"])

rule bwa:
    input:
        v = "data/ref.fna",
        read1 = lambda wildcards: FTP.remote(samples.loc[wildcards.sample, 'read1']),
        read2 = lambda wildcards: FTP.remote(samples.loc[wildcards.sample, 'read2'])
    output:
        "results/{sample}.sam"
    shell:
        "scripts/bwa-mem2-2.2.1_x64-linux/bwa-mem2 mem {input.v} {input.read1} {input.read2} > {output}"
```

**EDIT 2**
The issue with my original attempt is [snakemake doesn't allow lambda functions in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61905249/lambda-function-in-snakemake-output). So the following minimal working example:

```
read1={'s1': 'test1/ERR7671976_1.fastq.gz'}
read2={'s1': 'test1/ERR7671976_2.fastq.gz'}

rule all:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: read1[wildcards.sample],
        lambda wildcards: read2[wildcards.sample]

rule test:
    output:
        lambda wildcards: read1[wildcards.sample],
        lambda wildcards: read2[wildcards.sample]
    params:
        r1 = lambda wildcards: read1[wildcards.sample],
        r2 = lambda wildcards: read2[wildcards.sample]
    shell:
        """
        touch {params.r1}
        touch {params.r2}
        """
```

gets "SyntaxError: Only input files can be specified as functions", while the following (user-defined output filenames):

```
read1={'s1': 'test1/ERR7671976_1.fastq.gz'}
read2={'s1': 'test1/ERR7671976_2.fastq.gz'}

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{sample}_1.fastq.gz", sample=read1.keys()),
        expand("{sample}_2.fastq.gz", sample=read2.keys())

rule test:
    output:
        '{sample}_1.fastq.gz',
        '{sample}_2.fastq.gz'
    params:
        r1 = lambda wildcards: read1[wildcards.sample],
        r2 = lambda wildcards: read2[wildcards.sample]
    shell:
        """
        touch {params.r1}; mv {params.r1} {wildcards.sample}_1.fastq.gz
        touch {params.r2}; mv {params.r2} {wildcards.sample}_2.fastq.gz
        """
```

works fine.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for not using the snakemake internal [Remote file](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/remote_files.html#file-transfer-protocol-ftp) capabilities? Have you tried to remove `temp` from the files in `rule dl` and hardcoding the URLs for debugging?

Comment: thanks for your suggestions! I got it to work using remote(). I think the issue with my original attempt is snakemake [doesn't allow lambda functions in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61905249/lambda-function-in-snakemake-output). I have added a MWE in Edit 2.

Comment: You can post the solution you like and accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it's helpful, the following code using [remote files](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/remote_files.html#file-transfer-protocol-ftp) works (also suggested by euronion):

```
import pandas as pd
from snakemake.remote.FTP import RemoteProvider as FTPRemoteProvider

FTP = FTPRemoteProvider()

samples = pd.read_table("data.tsv").set_index("sample", drop=False)

rule all:
    input:
        expand("results/{sample}.sam", sample = samples["sample"])

rule bwa:
    input:
        v = "data/ref.fna",
        read1 = lambda wildcards: FTP.remote(samples.loc[wildcards.sample, 'read1']),
        read2 = lambda wildcards: FTP.remote(samples.loc[wildcards.sample, 'read2'])
    output:
        "results/{sample}.sam"
    shell:
        "scripts/bwa-mem2-2.2.1_x64-linux/bwa-mem2 mem {input.v} {input.read1} {input.read2} > {output}"
```

The issue with my original attempt is [snakemake doesn't allow lambda functions in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61905249/lambda-function-in-snakemake-output) (see Edit 2 above).